# How to maximize the volume of a rectangular parallelepiped in an ellipsoid?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, conic-sections

This question comes from an exam about 15 years ago.

> How to find the maximal volume of a rectangular parallelepiped inscribed in an ellipsoid $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$?

I think this should be solved by Lagrange mulitpliers. but it is not given that the parallelepiped is parallel to the axes, so I cannot apply the method immediately.
I tired to prove that the only parallelepiped in an ellipsoid must be parallel to the axes; even though this seems obvious, I found no way of proving it rigorously.
If I can prove this, then the ensuing steps by Lagrange are not so difficult to me.
So any help is well-appreciated.

Comment: Assuming the your claim is correct, I think you should show that the center of the ellipsoid coincides with the center of the box. Then you can show that the box must be axis-aligned.

Comment: And how should I show that the two centers coincide? At least the symmetry method does not seem to work...

Comment: I don't see why the parallelepiped must be parallel to the coordinate axes. Consider a sphere. Surely you can put a box which does not align with coordinate axes. Also, in less special cases, this still seems possible, for example $a=b$ then you could put a vertical box any old way, nothing special about $x$ and $y$ in that context. Surely, the argument that it must be parallel stems from some symmetry argument. Suppose otherwise and argue the volume is non-optimal.

Comment: Incidentally, I really like this question, I've taught Lagrange multipliers a few times, including this problem, nobody ever asks this. Nice thinking.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook I have also doubted whether my conjecture was true. But I could not see why a non-symmetric parallelepiped is not of optimal volume either. Also, thanks for pointing out that this is not true, even in some less special cases. now I have to think about the general cases...

Comment: @S.B. aren't the axes of that ellipsoid the coordinate axes?

Comment: How about an easier version to begin. Why is the maximum area parallelogram inscribed in an ellipse $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=1$ given by a rectangle which aligns with the $x,y$ axes? Or is it?

Comment: Just take a pair of parallel, non-coordinate, planes and let them intersect the ellipsoid symmetrically. Or is that impossible? For example, $x+y+z=d$ for two different values of $d$ ought to intersect the ellipsoid in two quartets of points. Do these quartets necessarily fail to line up? I can't see it without doing some calculation...

Comment: @JamesS.Cook I think it could be possible. Generalizing a fact about ellipse, I guess any ellipsoid can be determined by 9 points on its surface that are not on the same sphere. So we pick a box vertices and an arbitrary 9th point outside the box. It doesn't seem the box would be axis-aligned in general.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook WRT the paralellogram problem. A square inscribed in a radius 1 circle has area 2 units. If teh circle is 'squashed' by a factor of 2 along the x or y axis then the square's area is reduced by a factor of 2. Identical situation if the circle is squashed in the x+y or x-y axis - so at least one non parallel inscribed parallelogram has the same area as the axis-parallel one.

Comment: @MikeFee Don't you get a parallelogram after squashing instead of a rectangle? We are looking for largest inscribed **box**.

Comment: Apply a linear transformation with det=1 that turns yr ellipsoid into a sphere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply a linear transformation with det=1 that turns yr ellipsoid into a sphere. It transforms  the set of parallelepipeds inscribed in the ellipsoid into the set of parallelepipeds inscribed in the sphere, preserving their volumes. Show that the parallelepiped of maximum volume inscribed in the sphere is a cube. Transform back to the ellipsoid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The idea of using rigid transformations is great. Thanks again!